# Arduino Uno rev 3 toggling a 230 V submersible pump on intervals

Tags: arduino-uno, relay

I am software programmer and hobby farmer. While I was working on a [hydroponic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroponics) farming stuff, I had to use submersible pumps with timers. I don't want to buy timers that are actually a tedious scheduling process. so I am making one myself.

I want to toggle 230 V for turning a submersible pump(150-230 V and 18 W) ON/OFF. I read that Arduino may not able to supply enough input current that the relay requires. I am not sure about what transistor to use to amplify the input current. I came across a circuit diagram and a relay board. Do I still need to use a transistor and diode if I use this relay with an Arduino?

This is the [two-channel relay](http://www.ebay.in/itm/5V-2-Channel-Relay-Board-Module-10A-250AC-Opto-coupler-Arduino-Raspberry-Shield-/321432317541?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_203&hash=item4ad6dbee65) I am about to use and the circuit is below.

[image: Circuit to use relay with Arduino]

Should I follow the circuit if I am using this relay? The relay has a tolerance of 250 V. What if the voltage fluctuates above 250 V? I am going to use a 9 V battery to power the Arduino. Feel free to explain anything that I may have to know.

**UPDATE**

Thanks marla for making it clear that I don't need diodes and transistors. Andy, as you said, I can't keep changing batteries often, and it will limit the system. Shall I use an adapter which reads output 5 V and 1 amperes? Will that drive the Arduino and be sufficient for both the relays?

Comment: The relay board you will be using already has opto-coupler and transistor driver on the board. You can directly drive the board from your Arduino. Check out this stack exchange page (similar product) : http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18908/not-sure-how-to-wire-my-5vdc-to-120vac-arduino-relay-board

Comment: The relay coil will consume maybe 50 to 100 mA. This will reduce battery life dramatically.

Comment: @Andyaka could you please take a look at the update ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Arduino will easily drive this relay board, and it needs only a very small input current.

The board you linked to has a built-in optical isolation circuit, so there is no direct electrical connection between the Arduino-side of the circuit and the relay side. This *should* protect your Arduino if something goes wrong. For what it's worth, the product description specifies this board is suitable for "AC [...] appliances such as [...] motors". A pump is primarily a motor.

The voltage may fluctuate when the pump is started and stopped ([Back-EMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-electromotive_force)). It's hard to say what this might do to the relay board if it goes way over specification. Perhaps you might be happier with a much more robust [solid-state relay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_relay) (SSR) that has a higher rating than the target load. Something 
like *[SSR-25DA 25A Solid State Relay - White](http://www.dx.com/p/ssr-25da-25a-solid-state-relay-white-134494)*. Since solid-state relays are non-mechanical, they will not wear-out from repeated switching either.

You may also want to build some fail-safe sensors into your project. For example, water level float switches for both high-water and low-water marks.

Comment: I am not using solar power now. but thinking about failsafe. i power arduino from wall wart dc supply. so incase of mains failure i want to supply from battery so my arduino wont restart and mess things.